# WebGL on Google Chrome with AMD card

Tags: google-chrome, ati, webgl

When I try to use Cooliris for Google Chrome it shows the following message

> WebGL did not initialize properly. Make sure you are running the latest version of Chrome.

I have an AMD/ATI video card. How to fix this? Google Chrome version is 13.0.782.218

http://get.webgl.org/ says "Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the latest drivers for your video card."

Catalyst Control Center says "Catalyst version 11.5 and Driver Packaging Version 8.84.6-110324a-116088C-ATI"

`google-chrome --enable-webgl` didn't work

Comment: @JaderDias Please make edits to your post instead of posting information in the comments. Doing so will provide a higher quality experience for all users.

Comment: Firefox now supports webgl and its available on linux :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WebGL on Google Chrome, it is available *BUT* not on Linux, actually there's a lot of questions regarding this in Google groups and the Chromium issue tracker. This happens in both x86 and x86-64 versions.

Running `google-chrome  --enable-webgl --in-process-webgl`  or `google-chrome  --enable-webgl`doesn't have any effect on the browser.

get.webgl.org Mentions this:

- Hmm. While your browser seems to support WebGL, it is disabled or
  unavailable. If possible, please ensure that you are running the
  latest drivers for your video card.

If you now then go an click on the Wiki link, and then on *How to Get a WebGL Implementation* you'll see this:

- **Chrome**
- WebGL is available in the stable release of Chrome. Please    report
  issues you find to either the public WebGL mailing list or via    the
  Chromium issue tracker.

***THIS*** is only half-true as  neither the stable or the dev. versions of Chrome have WebGL available on Linux. (OP is using the Stable release and i'm using the dev. release)

Comment: NOTE: one of the google groups messages actually suggests to use firefox if one needs to try webgl, so there is support for linux it's just chrome that doesn't support it.

Comment: Seems to work just fine on Firefox, any idea why Chrome still doesn't supports it?

Answer (score 2):

The following steps allow me to run demos on [threejs.org](http://threejs.org):

> On the page `chrome://flags/`

- Override software rendering list (select `enable`)
- Disable WebGL. (select `disable`)

You can check that WebGL is enabled by using the following page:

> `chrome://gpu/`

For reference, I am running:

- Chromium 24.0.1312.56
- Ubuntu 12.04 (x64, Desktop)
- ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series
- OpenGL: 3.3.11627

Answer (score 1):

Even if the browser you are using is capable of running webgl your computer may not be able to

If you run this command in a terminal

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

You should get back some thing like this

```
OpenGL version string: 1.5 Mesa 7.9-devel
```

If the first number is lower than 2.1 you wont be able to run webgl in any browser unfortunately

This is a quote from Benoit Jacob a Firefox developer

> Even though WebGL is closest to OpenGL ES v2, every WebGL
>   implementation that I know, including ours, supports desktop OpenGL
>   too, but you need at least OpenGL 2.1 because WebGL is entirely based
>   on the programmable pipeline. So indeed, OpenGL 1.5 is not good
>   enough.

BTW my own card is a ATI Xpress 200M which has a opengl version of 1.5 and I cant use webgl in any browsers.

Comment: some people should need to `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` before using glxinfo