# How to get WebGL to work in the Chromium webbrowser?

Tags: 11.10, webgl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebGL on Google Chrome with AMD card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59754/webgl-on-google-chrome-with-amd-card)

I want to try WebGL but I am not able to get it working on my computer.
I have the i3-2100 CPU, an ASUS P8z68-v LX motherboard and no dedicated graphic card.

I am using Chromium and Ubuntu 11.10

Can anybody explain to me, how I can get webGl to work on my machine ?

Comment: @UriHerrera I don't think so, they don't talk about a dedicated graphics card, so I don't think its a duplicate.

Comment: @jrg Regardless of the GPU WebGl doesn't work yet.

Comment: @UriHerrera I see. So the answer is, "you can't because Chrom(ium)e doesn't have it yet for linux users"?

Comment: @jrg That is Correct.